# Make ProgressBar overlaid over VideoView display immediately

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-progressbar

I have a ProgressBar and a VideoView both inside a RelativeLayout, with the ProgressBar floating above the VideoView in z-order (after it in the XML).  The ProgressBar is indeterminate.  When I switch video sources, I display the ProgressBar until the new video is playing, by setting its visibility to View.VISIBLE.  I am doing this in the UI thread.

But my ProgressBar doesn't display immediately, although my logging statement (also in the UI thread, immediately before the setVisibility() call) occurs immediately.  It takes a few (2 or 3) seconds.  I have tried many things to make the ProgressBar display immediately and have run out of ideas.

- add an animation (to the ProgressBar; also to the RelativeLayout)
- make the visibility change happen on animation end
- progressBar.bringToFront()
- progressBar.invalidate() and postInvalidate()
- relativeLayout.invalidate() and postInvalidate()

How can I make the ProgressBar appear immediately?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly try invalidating the complete view or do setContentView(R.layout.abc);

What I do in similar cases also is to start the subsequent code with a scheduler so that the UI screen update has time to update and does not get pushed back in priority. Even 0.5 secs are often enough if you can do this in your code...?

Comment: that's really strange - so far it always worked in my cases. There must be some other tasks that keep the UI from updating then I guess. Does it even not work with a 2-3 sec delay? Then for sure, there must be something that keeps the UI from updating!

Comment: I think what is happening is a lot of UI-thread blocking from other methods.  The code is pretty badly tangled.